# Don't select an item if there's a row in another table matching those details

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to only show an item if it exists in products, and bids, but if the id matches a row in the orders table don't select it, here's the sql I have up to now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products 
       RIGHT JOIN bids 
               ON bids.bids_item = id 
WHERE  username = ? 
       AND Now() > enddate 
       AND enabled = 1 
GROUP  BY bids.bids_item 
ORDER  BY enddate
```

I'm trying to do it if bids.bids_item exists as orders.orders_product then not to select, but if it doesn't then select the row. How would I go about doing that?

Tables:

```
products
   id
orders
   orders.order_product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to why you'd use a right join on bids when you said that it needs to be included in both `products` and `bids` to be a potential candidate for inclusion.  Additionally, consistent use of `[alias].[column]` would make it easier to understand for me as an answerer, and anyone looking at the code in the future.  That said, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN bids b ON b.bids_item = p.id -- inner join on bids as we only want to include when exists in both p and b
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.id = o.orders_product
WHERE o.orders_product IS NULL -- left join and filter where p.id does not exist in o
   and username = ? 
   AND Now() > enddate 
   AND enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sub-query with `NOT IN` . I am not writhing the whole query for you but the idea is like this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE bids.bids_item NOT IN ( SELECT orders_product FROM orders);
```